# How to setup TypeLite to build types in other projects

Tags: typelite

I'm working in MS Dynamics CRM, and I have a WebResources project that contains all of my TypeScript.  I have Plugin .net library dll that contains some POCO objects that will be returned via Rest to my javascript in my WebResources project.  How do I setup TypeLite to build my Typescript files?

This is my assumption.

1. Install Typescript NuGet Package in my Plugin project
2. Decorate the POCO classes I need Typescript files for, with the `[TsClass]` attribute
3. Upon build, it will generate the Typescript Files to the Scripts folder that it will create in the Plugin project
4. I create a postbuild event that copies the Typescript files over to my WebResources Project

Is there an easier way?
Did I make an incorrect assumption?

### Update

From Lukas's answer, I've updated my TypeLite.Net4.tt file to look like this:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="True" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(TargetDir)TypeLite.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(TargetDir)TypeLite.Net4.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(TargetDir)Xrm.Plugins.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)" #>

<#@ import namespace="TypeLite" #> 
<#@ import namespace="TypeLite.Net4" #> 
<#@output extension=".d.ts"#>
<#@include file="Manager.ttinclude"#>
<# var manager = Manager.Create(Host, GenerationEnvironment); #>

<# var ts = TypeScript.Definitions()
        .WithReference("Enums.ts")
        .For<Xrm.Plugins.Rest.Poco.AccountLookupResponse>();
#>

<#= ts.Generate(TsGeneratorOutput.Properties) #>

<# manager.StartNewFile("Enums.ts"); #>
<#= ts.Generate(TsGeneratorOutput.Enums) #>
<# manager.EndBlock(); #>
<# manager.Process(true); #>
```

This generates the correct definition in the TypeLite.Net4.d.ts file.  I'm not currently using any enums in my class, so the Enums.ts is not necessary currently, but it doesn't hurt to have it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is another way, but I am not sure, whether it is better.

1. install TypeLITE.Lib package to your Plugin project (you need reference TypeLITE library there, because you want to use the [TsClass] attribute)
2. install TypeLITE package to your WebResources project and modify TypeLite.tt file to include a reference to your plugin.dll

   <#@ assembly name="$(TargetDir)plugin.dll" #>

alternatively you can skip the first step and use fluent configuration `TypeScript.Definitions().For<YourClass>()` to include specific classes in the output file

Comment: I'll attempt to use your "alternatively" option and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: I posted an update where I show the TT file.  Should I have commented out the lines that I did?  Does anything else need to be changed that you see?

Comment: It looks OK. You might need to include `.WithReference("Enums.ts")` if you use any enums in your class

Comment: Ok, I've kept it in there.